# Testing redirect after submit with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-router-v4, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a login component. Specifically that it redirects on a successful login. It works fine when testing it manually. But in my test it never does the redirect and it can therefor not find the "Logout" link:

```
test('successfully logs the in the user', async () => {
  const fakeUserResponse = {success: true, token: 'fake_user_token'}
  jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      json: () => Promise.resolve(fakeUserResponse),
    })
  })
  const { getByText, getByLabelText, findByTestId } = render(<Router><Login /></Router>)

  fireEvent.change(getByLabelText(/email/i), {target: {value: 'dan@example.com'}})
  fireEvent.change(getByLabelText(/password/i), {target: {value: 'password1234'}})
  fireEvent.click(getByText(/submit/i))

  await waitForElement(() => getByText(/logout/i));
})
```

I'm redirecting with `react-router` version 4, like so:

```
{state.resolved ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 14):

You can mock the `Redirect` component's implementation to show some text including the path instead of redirecting to it:

```js
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
  return {
    Redirect: jest.fn(({ to }) => `Redirected to ${to}`),
  };
});
```

and expect your component to display the text with the correct path:

```js
expect(screen.getByText('Redirected to /')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: This, I found, is the best way to mock and test Redirect with react-router-dom. As a best practice, I also tend to unmock the package after all tests have ran - like ```afterAll(() => { jest.unmock('react-router-dom'); });```

Answer (score 10):

In my case, this gets the job done:

```
it('should do stuff and redirect to /some/route', async () => {
  // given
  const history = createMemoryHistory();

  // when
  render(<Router history={history}><MyComponent /></Router>);

  // do stuff which leads to redirection

  // then
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/some/route');
  });
});
```

Comment: When using this with React router 6.4 I get the error `ReferenceError: Request is not defined`

Answer (score 9):

Personally I mock the `history.replace` function that is used by the `Redirect` component.

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
history.replace = jest.fn();

render(
  <Router history={history} >
    <Component />
  </Router>
);

// trigger redirect

expect(history.replace).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
  "pathname": "/SamplePath",
  "search": "?SampleSearch",
  "state": { "Sample": "State" }
}));
```

This allows you to check for more than just the correct path.
Please ensure you are using `Router` and not `BrowserRouter` in your test. The latter does not accept a history prop.

Answer (score 4):

So I ended up doing this:

```
const { getByText, getByLabelText, } = render(
  <Router>
    <Login/>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/">
        <div>logged out</div>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

fireEvent.change(getByLabelText(/email/i), {target: {value: 'dan@example.com'}})
fireEvent.change(getByLabelText(/password/i), {target: {value: 'password1234'}})
fireEvent.click(getByText(/submit/i))

await waitForElement(() => getByText(/logged out/i))
```