# How to test signin component with jest and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I try to create an integrated test for a sign in component but I am facing some issues. Basically I need to check that after entered email and password credentials and clicked the submit button, it redirect me to a given page. I am using `waitForComponentToBeRemoved` to check the none presence of email or password field of the sign in component but I got an error:

`Timed out in waitForElementToBeRemoved.`

Please tell me if i dont have the right approach or if you need further informations.

Here is the test:

```
    it( 'Login with real username and password', async () => {



        beforeEach(() => {
            fetch.dontMock()
        })


        act(() => {
            ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
        })

        // log /
        console.log('history', window.location.pathname)

        const email = process.env.TEST_EMAIL
        const password = process.env.TEST_PASSWORD

        const signInButton = screen.getByTestId('landing-signin')

        fireEvent.click(signInButton)


        await waitFor(async () => {
            expect(signInButton).not.toBeInTheDocument()

            // log /signin
            console.log('history', window.location.pathname)
        })

        
        const emailField = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Email address')

        const passwordField = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Your password')
        const button = screen.getByTestId('submit-button')

        expect(button).toBeInTheDocument()
        expect(passwordField).toBeInTheDocument()
        expect(emailField).toBeInTheDocument()

        userEvent.type(emailField, email)
        userEvent.type(passwordField, password)


        await act(async () => {

            fireEvent.click(button)

        })

        // Timed out in waitForElementToBeRemoved.
        await waitForElementToBeRemoved(button).then(() => {

            console.log('element has been removed')
        })

        // i need something to wait the response and the redirection to be done

    })
```

ps: I dont want to mock data, it need to do real api call

Answer (score 1):

How to you do the `redirect` in your source code? Are you using `react-router`? (In this case you could simply mock the redirect function and check if it has been called!?)

Please check out this related question: [Testing redirect after submit with React Testing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362930/testing-redirect-after-submit-with-react-testing-library)

Kent C Dodds is building and testing a simple sign-in component in this video (starting at timestamp 14:30):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eg_TFYF_cKM&t=869s&ab_channel=Applitools%3AVisualAIPoweredTestAutomation

Comment: The second link doesnt redirect to a video

Comment: sorry fixed it.